# Xamarin.Forms Compiled Bindings does not work on DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am having trouble with [Use compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate).

I added `XamlComilation` in *App.xaml.cs*

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Solution.Project
```

And I changed my `DataTemplate` to

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RectLayerDataTemplate" x:DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:RectLayerViewModel}">
    <forms:RectLayerView forms:ValueX="{Binding ValueX}"
                         forms:ValueY="{Binding ValueY}"
                         forms:ValueWidth="{Binding ValueWidth}"
                         forms:ValueHeight="{Binding ValueHeight}"
                         forms:Color="{Binding Color}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

However, `DataTemplate` does not applied to `BindableLayout.ItemSource`.

```
<AbsoluteLayout x:Name="CanvasLayout"
                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LayerViewModels}" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you use `AbsoluteLayout` to make the layout overlap, so you think it didn't work?

I create a simple sample,with the `DataTemplate` and set it to the `StackLayout` `BindableLayout`,it works well.

the page.xaml:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="CanvasLayout" Orientation="Vertical"
             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding LayerViewModels}" />
```

page.xam.cs:

```
public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyData();          
        LayerDataTemplate s = new LayerDataTemplate();
        BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate(CanvasLayout, s.template);
    }
```

**MyData** :

```
public class MyData
{

    public ObservableCollection<RectLayerViewModel> LayerViewModels { set; get; } = new ObservableCollection<RectLayerViewModel>();

    public MyData()
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++)
        {
            LayerViewModels.Add(new RectLayerViewModel { Name = $"Added at {LayerViewModels.Count}", Type = 1 });
        }
    }
}
```

**RectLayerViewModel**:

```
public class RectLayerViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

**DataTemplate**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"     
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:EntryCa"
         x:Class="EntryCa.LayerDataTemplate">
<DataTemplate x:Key="RectLayerDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:RectLayerViewModel">

         <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                   TextColor="Red"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
  
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Hello, @Leo Zhu - MSFT. Sorry for bother you again. I already have working sample, which uses `DataTemplateSelector`. So I don't think `AbsoluteLayout` is not a matter here. I am trying to get same result with `x:DataType` because my colleagues are familiar with WPF than Xamarin. By the way, In your code, I can't get it `s.template` means. `LayerTemplate` is ResourceDictionary with multiple `DataTemplate`. But, [BindableLayout.SetItemTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindablelayout.setitemtemplate?view=xamarin-forms) is only apply one `DataTemplate` to all.

Comment: In short, **is there a way matching View and ViewModel by `x:DataType` without using `DataTemplateSelector`?**

Comment: I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43411870/how-to-get-xdatatype-for-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-for-custom-datatemplatesel) I need.

Answer (score 0):

Sample usage of [compiled bindings in a DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings#use-compiled-bindings-in-a-datatemplate). Below `ItemViewModel` is the type of the items in a `ListView.ItemsSource`:

XAML:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyViewModels"
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:ItemViewModel" >
...

<ListView ... ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListViewItemTemplate}"/>
```

ItemViewModel:

```
namespace MyViewModels
{
  public class ItemViewModel : ViewModelPropertyBase
  ...

  public abstract class ViewModelPropertyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
  ...
```